# Unity - How to get individual tile from an overlap collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Im working on a space mining game and trying to get a mining laser beam fired from the player and delete tiles in a tilemap the beam overlaps with. Beam is a static sustained rectangle from the players gun. The below is how ive traditionally gotten overlaps before but its returning a 0,0,0 coordinate always which i think is the tilemap as a whole and not the individual tiles im overlapping with as "targets" returns just 1 constant result.

Can anyone with a brain wrinklier than mine help me fix this code so i get the individual tiles position and not the tilemap as a whole?

Picture of inspector for the destructable tilemap:
[image]

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float range;
    private Tilemap tilemap;
    private GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {// Start is called before the first frame update

        tilemap = GameObject.Find("Destructible Tiles").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }
        
    void Update()
    {// Update is called once per frame

        PlayerInput();
    }

    private void PlayerInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {//left mouse click
            Fire();
        }
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        //player coords
        float px = player.transform.position.x;
        float py = player.transform.position.y;

        //coords for box overlap centerpoint
        float offset;

        if (range <= 1)
        {
            offset = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            offset = (range / 2) + 0.5f;
        }

        //get all targets in range of laser
        Collider2D[] targets = { };

        if (player.transform.localScale.x == 1)
        {//facing right

            targets = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(new Vector2(px + offset, py), new Vector2(range, 0.1f), 0);
        }
        else if (player.transform.localScale.x == -1)
        {//facing left

            targets = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(new Vector2(px - offset, py), new Vector2(range, 0.1f), 0);
        }
        
        foreach (Collider2D target in targets)
        {
            if (target.tag == "Ground")
            {//target is minable
                Vector3Int tile = tilemap.WorldToCell(target.transform.position);
                tilemap.SetTile(tile, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried to get an array of individual tiles in the overlapboxall but get the tilemap as a whole

Comment: Get where it hits and get the tile ar that location

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer using a raycast instead of an overlap or a collider in trigger mode. The issue is with any intangible detection there is no "contact" with the object like bumping into it with a non trigger collider. Raycast has a collision component ("point") that you can get coordinates from. For those who had to suffer through this problem and turned google purple over it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using static UnityEngine.GraphicsBuffer;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float range;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask laserTargets;

    private Tilemap tilemap;
    private GameObject player;

    void Start()
    {// Start is called before the first frame update

        tilemap = GameObject.Find("Destructible Tiles").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }
        
    void Update()
    {// Update is called once per frame

        PlayerInput();
    }

    private void PlayerInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {//left mouse click
            Fire();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void Fire()
    {//fire laser and check for contacts

        RaycastHit2D ray = new RaycastHit2D();

        if (player.transform.localScale.x == 1)
        {//facing right
            ray = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, range, laserTargets);
        }
        else if (player.transform.localScale.x == -1)
        {//facing left
            ray = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.left, range, laserTargets);
        }

        if (ray.collider == true)
        {//ray has a hit return

            if (ray.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
            {//hit is minable

                //get coords of ray contact and translate into tile coordinates
                Vector3 hitpos = Vector3.zero;
                hitpos.x = ray.point.x - 0.01f * ray.normal.x;
                hitpos.y = ray.point.y - 0.01f * ray.normal.y;
                Vector3Int tile = tilemap.WorldToCell(hitpos);

                //set tile to empty
                tilemap.SetTile(tile, null);
            }
        }
    }
```